# Stopping a proc from another proc

Tags: sql-server

I have a proc which making some mathematical calculation. On the UI when user click calculation button this proc is called. This proc calling few proc on the basis of condition which we can pass as parameter. Now i want to implement a way when user click on stop calculation button all calculations should be stop and rollback.  How can i implement it from sql side or is there any way by which i can stop to execute main proc by the help of another proc.

ThankYou

Answer (score 0):

If you are establishing a separate connection to run the calculations, you could use the `KILL` statement to terminate that session.

`KILL` accepts an argument, which in your particular case would be the session ID assigned to the server connection.

Note that `KILL` implies rolling back any pending transactions (in that session), which may take some time too. (The time would depend on the amount of changes pending when `KILL` was issued.)

Read more about the command [in the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173730.aspx).